# turn on numlock at login screen. GDM

Tags: rhel, gnome3, gdm, gdm3, numlock

GDM is turning off numlock key.

I have tried following:

```
a) installing numlockx and inserting following lines at /etc/gdm/Init/Default
if [ -x /usr/bin/numlockx ]; then
    /usr/bin/numlockx on
fi

b) Using setleds +num, but it corrupts the numlock state.
```

When I reboot the system or gdm.service

```
Numlock becomes on at boot
Numlock turns off at login screen[GDM]
Numlock again turns on after login. [ KDE / GNOME ]
```

How can I ensure numlock is always on at login (gdm).

Comment: Did none of the methods mentioned here work : https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Activating_Numlock_on_Bootup ?

Comment: No, none of them worked. I have already tried them. Numlock was turned on  before the login screen but during the login screen is displayed it turns off.

Comment: @user746184 - try setting it via gsettings as the _gdm_ user - as I explained [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/205058). Use `gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.peripherals.keyboard numlock-state on` instead of the command I used there...

Comment: Have you tried putting your `numlockx on` script in `less /etc/gdm3/PreSession/Default`?

Answer (score 1):

following the tip by @don_crissti i successfully enabled numlock on gdm login screen like this:

```
sudo su #become root
su gdm -s /bin/sh #become gdm user with a shell
#do the work i don't 100% understand
export $(dbus-launcher) 
GSETTINGS_BACKEND=dconf gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.peripherals.keyboard numlock-state on
exit #drop back to root user
systemctl restart gdm #restart gdm
```