# How to disable the user list on GDM3 login screen?

Tags: arch-linux, gnome3, gdm3

**Environment:**

Distribution: `Arch Linux`

Display Manager: `GDM 3.16.x`

Dekstop Environment: `Gnome 3.16`

**Question:**

How to disable the user list displayed on the login screen?

**Clarification:**

*Wanted result:*

In effect, from the users perspective, the result: Being presented with a box that requests a username upon reaching the login screen.

*Not a solution:*

Making the given users into systemusers is not a very good solution.

*Preferred method of achieving the wanted result*

What exact packages do I need to install or disable?

If not through packages then what utilities should I use to configure the needed setting?

If lower-level configuration is required, what manual settings do I need to change in what files (filepaths please)?

Comment: @don_crissti Is this an acceptable presentation of the question? And thank you for your clear clarification: I truly appreciate it!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should work with `gdm ≥ 3.12` (tested on `archlinux` w. `gdm 3.16.1`):

1. switch to a `VT` (e.g. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd>), login as *root* and run:

   ```
   su - gdm -s /bin/sh
   ```

   to switch user to `gdm`.
2. then run:

   ```
   export $(dbus-launch)
   ```

   and:

   ```
   GSETTINGS_BACKEND=dconf gsettings set org.gnome.login-screen disable-user-list true
   ```

   run `exit` or hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> to return to *root* account.
3. restart the display manager:

   ```
   systemctl restart gdm
   ```

Reverting is pretty much the same, just change `true` to `false` @ step 2.

Answer (score 0):

You could try replacing GDM with a different login manager, like KDM, LXDM, LightDM, SLiM or XDM.  These may have better configurability.  In fact, on this page are some screenshots: https://wiki.mageia.org/en/Display_Managers .  SLiM looks like there is no user list, although others could be configured to look the same.